# RelativeLayout background rendering over children

Tags: android, android-layout

I have this (simplified) layout.-

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background_pattern" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dimen5"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen15"
        android:background="@drawable/background_grey" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/logo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_logo"
            android:src="@drawable/app_logo" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Which renders good in eclipse layout editor: my `app_logo` image over `background_grey`, which is over `background_pattern` image. But when I run on device, `background_grey` renders over `background_pattern` as expected, but also over its child `app_logo`.

**Am I doing something wrong or is this some kind of bug when nesting several layouts with background attribute?**

As a workaround, I suppose I can replace background attributes for `ImageViews`, but I'm pretty sure this may work and I'm missing something obvious.

**Notes**
*Working with the latest ADT and deploying on Nexus 4, 4.2.2*
*`background_grey` is a 9-patch image*

Comment: How can you tell that background_grey is rendered over the app_logo? If the app_logo isn't visible, might it not just as well be that the ImageView isn't rendered at all? Is the app_logo visible if you use a semi transparent color like #88000000 instead of background_grey?

Comment: Mmh you're right, it seems the `ImageView` isn't rendered, but the weird thing is that the `RelativeLayout` is wrapping correctly to the image height. Forgot to mention, but `background_grey` is a 9-patch, could it have something to do?